# what is the best way to parse array of dictionaries in JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, data-structures

I have a huge JSON data which is containing array of dictionaries, and each dictionary containing lots of key-value pares.

I have to parse each dictionary into models(NSObject models).

What is the best and good way to do this? Right now i am converting the JSON using SBJSON framework and iterating the array and then storing each key-value, in dictionary, to NSObject model.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An informal protocol, `NSKeyValueCoding`, is likely what you want. It contains a `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` method, that will let you turn a dictionary into an Objective-C object of your choice. Assuming the key names match the property names, that is.

Combine that with a `for` loop, and, you've got a pretty quick way to make native ObjC objects from JSON.

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason why key-value method is quicker than others.

Comment: Its quicker to write, because there will be much less code. I'm not sure about the performance impact of using KVC (instead of foo.key = dictionary[@"key"];), but, it has never been a concern for me -- whenever I'm profiling my code with Instruments, there are bigger fish to fix.

Answer (score 0):

use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

**Example:**

```
String predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ == '%@'", key, value];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *filteredResults = [allResultsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

When using a dynamic key, you should use the `%K` token instead of `%@`

Example:

`NSString predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, value];`

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) article describes the syntax of the predicate string and some aspects of the predicate parser.